# Matlab: consonance (superposition) of recorded sounds

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I make a project - Piano simulator in Matlab. I am able to play multiple sounds in the same time:

```
M=length(number);
freq_sampling = handles.freq_sampling;

for i=1:M
    filename_in=['audio/' num2str(number(i)) '.mat'];
    load(filename_in)
        try %just for safety
            y_sound=y_sound+y;
        catch
            y_sound=y;
        end
end

sound(y_sound,freq_sampling)
```

Problem is with recording and playing it later - this code below concatenates all pressed buttons into one sound vector:

```
if record_on == 1
  sound_vector_long = handles.sound_vector;
  mono = (y_sound(:,1)+y_sound(:,2))/2; %mono is needed cuz .mat files are 2ch
  if sound_vector_long == 0
    sound_vector_long = transpose(mono);
  else
    sound_vector_long = cat(2, sound_vector_long, transpose(mono));
  end
  handles.sound_vector = sound_vector_long;

  guidata(handles.figure1, handles);
end
```

But I'd like to play the music like in real-time when I press multiple buttons - is it possible to do?

P.S. For sure, the final sound vector would have a different (shorter) length and some of the values would be a superposition of two (or more) vector's values. I just don't have an idea how to do this superposition (to do a consonance in result).