# Printing the spectrogram with a GUIDE script

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

could you help me why this code doesn't work?

```
freq = 440;
samples = 0:1/44100:1.4;
x = sin(2*pi*freq*samples);
axes(handles.uipanel1);

spectrogram(x,'yaxis');
```

I'd like to print (somehow) a spectrogram in a specific UIpanel but I can't manage to do it. This code works fine in a separate .m file but not in my GUIDE script - shows empty standard plot and error: "Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object."

Also, I'd like to print this spectrogram independently - not by any kind of buttons, just printing at the start. Should it be assigned to any sort of uipanel1_Callback or OpeningFcn?

Comment: Can you show the actual GUIDE code?

Comment: @Suever my GUIDE is nearly 2000 lines of code, so please - consider some clean GUIDE file, where UIpanel1 is a main one

Comment: At least show the function that contains the code above

Comment: @Suever this is full body of a function, tried to used it in many e.g. `function pushbutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)`

Comment: If you put it inside of a function with that signature (it has the `handles` input) then it should be fine unless you put it in the `OpeningFcn` in which the uipanel isn't created yet.

Comment: @Suever unfortunately, it returns error like in my first post: "Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object."

Comment: Please post your actual 2000 lines of code in a pastebin or something otherwise it's hard to say what the issue is apart from the fact that `handles` isn't a `struct` as you expect

Comment: @Suever Well, posting all of it is not a good idea but here's the clean GUIDE script with the same error - it has one button and I want to show spectrogram in a window when I click it.

http://pastebin.com/9iizpWRv

Could you tell me what's wrong? Error is exactly the same, nonetheless these last 4 lines of code work fine in an empty .m file.

Comment: What line is giving you an error. You aren't using `handles.uipanel1` in the code you've posted...

Comment: Because this is maximally simplified example (figure1, pushbutton1 - nothing more), but problem remains the same.

Full error lines are too long to post here so... http://pastebin.com/qz9khWKE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the `spectrogram` function expects the figure toolbar to be visible because it attempts to get the handle to the 3D rotation tool. It does *not* check to see if the tool *actually exists* and this is causing your error.

```
hRotate = uigettool(ancestor(h,'Figure'),'Exploration.Rotate');
if strcmp(hRotate.State,'off')
```

In my opinion, this is a bug in MATLAB.

Your options are to either:

1. Add the standard figure toolbar to your GUI. You can do this either programmatically in your `OpeningFcn` so that `spectrogram` can find it

   ```
   set(handles.hfig, 'Toolbar', 'figure')
   ```

   Or you can add the toolbar [using GUIDE](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/creating-toolbars.html#brall4e)
2. Temporarily add a tool that mimics the rotation tool right before calling `spectrogram` and then delete it after calling `spectrogram`

   ```
   htoolbar = uitoolbar('Parent', ancestor(hObject, 'figure'));
   uitoggletool('Parent', htoolbar, 'Tag', 'Exploration.Rotate', 'State', 'off');

   spectrogram(...)

   % Delete the toolbar
   delete(htoolbar)
   ```

Comment: thank you, your answer should be pinned somewhere because I've searched over 100 links on MATLAB Central and stack and there was no single word about temporary toolbox's need. It works like a charm now.
If you don't mind, could you also look at my friend's post about some Matlab and audio processing as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016646/consonance-superposition-of-recorded-sounds-in-matlab